# empty lists within lists

Tags: python, list, nested

I am trying to empty a nested list in a python script:

```
deadBody_inv = [['AK47', 30],['M16', 30],['FragGrenade', 5],['Hunting Knife', 1]]

def search_body(deadBody):
   option = str(input("""\n\nYou enter the destroyed 
   bunker to find a dead enemy soldier./n
   A).Dispose Body
   B).Search Body  \n\n...>"""))

if option.lower() == 'a':
    inv_len = len(deadBody)
    for k in range(0, inv_len): 
        inv_len.remove(k)
```

I keep getting this error:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'remove'

im sure I am doing this wrong, I'm simply trying to remove each value of the list within a list. I figured the for loop would iterate through each 
list value(store it in k) and use the .remove() method to remove each value

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `inv_len = len(deadBody)` defines `inv_len` to be a simple integer. What does it mean to remove `k` from an integer? In any event, lists have a `clear()` method -- there is no reason to delete all elements in a loop.

Comment: It's unclear to me what the expected result is.

Comment: thanks I've used the clear() function for the list, I simply wished to empty the contents of the list. just trying to practise lists and dictionaries in a few script files thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if option.lower() == 'a':
    items = []
    while len(deadBody) > 0:
        items.append(deadBody.pop())
```

The array items will contain all of the items looted from `deadBody`

Additionally, if you have a list for the player's inventory, just use

```
player.extend(deadBody)
deadBody = [] # or alternatively, del deadBody
```

Comment: im not trying to get all the items option (a) is too dispose of the body, deleting each item within the list

Comment: @SidMicheals Just use `del deadBody` then

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'deadBody' referenced before assignment the list deadBody is a local variable using del() causing an unbound local error

Comment: @SidMicheals I would advise reading about python scoping first.

Comment: currently working through "Automate the boring stuff in python"

Answer (score 0):

```
inv_len = len(deadBody)
```

This is equal to the length of deadBody. Just use something that empties dead body and if you want to add them to your inventory. Such as:

```
player_inv.extend(deadBody)
deadBody.clear() #deadBody is now an empty list
```

Answer (score 0):

You're storing an int in inv_len then telling it to remove from the int.

I *think* you're trying to remove all items from deadBody, if you want do that just reassign deadBody to an empty list.

`deadBody = []`